# How to improve the performance of this method to get relative path from to/from path?

Tags: java, performance, indexing, data-structures, path

**Inputs :**
*fromPath -> "/a/b/c"*
 *toPath -> "a/b/d/f"*

**Output :** 
*relativePath -> "/../../d/f*

```
    public static String getRelativePath(String from, String to) {
    String relative = "";
    String regexPath = "/";
    String regexLow = "..";

    List<String> toList = Arrays.asList(to.split(regexPath));
    List<String> fromList = Arrays.asList(from.split(regexPath));

    int toSize = toList.size();
    int fromSize = fromList.size();

    relative += regexPath;

    for(int index = 0; index < fromSize; index++) {
        if(index <= toSize-1) {
            String toValue = toList.get(index);
            String fromValue = fromList.get(index);

            if(toValue.equals(fromValue)) {
                relative += regexLow + regexPath;
            }
            else
                relative += fromValue + regexPath;
        }
        else {
            if(index != fromSize-1)
                relative += fromList.get(index) + regexPath;
            else
                relative += fromList.get(index);
        }
    }

    return relative;
}
```

Is there a better way to optimize/execute this code? Started with nested loops then went directly with the index.

Comment: If your code works and you look for improvements, then you may ask this on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `O(n*2) = O(n)`. This code needs `O(n²)` in the worst case however.

Comment: You are right @fabian. I meant the execution is "doubled" when we use nested loops.

Comment: You really should use a `StringBuilder`. Otherwise the string concatenation causes a `O(n²)` performance where you could get `O(n)`.